# Laravel multilevel releationship

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, relational-database

I want to make JSON response like this:

```
{
  "title": "Category title",
  "description": "Category description",
  "articles": [
    {
      "title": "Article title",
      "comments": [
        {
          "user_name": "User Name",
          "text": "Coment text"
        },
        {
          "user_name": "User Name",
          "text": "Coment text"
        }  
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Application has categories table

```
categories
   id
   title
   description
```

And also category_articles table

```
category_articles
   id
   category_id
   article_id
```

Category model has this relationship

```
public function articles()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryArticles', 'category_id');
}
```

As you can see there is no straight relationship between category and articles
because articles kind of independent table which will be used in different parts
of application

Here is articles table

```
articles
  id
  title
  body
```

Articles has many comments relationship

```
comments
   id
   user_id
```

And also comment has relationship to user

So, I need to return response like I showed on the beginning.
I've stack like right here in the controller.

```
 public function show(Category $category) 
 {

 }
```

How should I implement my code to get response like this? Should I use resource for this?

Answer (score 1):

`articles` should be a `BelongsToMany` relationship:

```php
public function articles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'category_articles');
}
```

Then use eager loading:

```php
$categories = Category::with('articles.comments')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

A hasMany relationship is used in a situation like:
A user has many cars (but cars are only unique to one user)
Has 2 model and 2 tables (1 having all the data i.e. cars along with a reference to user i.e. user_id)

In your case it would be a belongsToMany relationship
A user has many offices (but there are more users/fans/lights etc associated with that office)
Has 3 tables (users, offices, a pivot table user_office (with user_id and office_id)